# Function produces NA when increasing size of data

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I am implementing my function in R and trying to the results to determine whether it is what I expect it to be. The function I am trying to evaluate is:

[image]

The function works fine till I increase the size of my data matrix (e.g it works for N = 10 but not when N = 12 and an example will be posted below.)

I am sure whether there is something to do with either my implementation or issues with overflow.

```
# Generate Sample Data
gen.sample <- function(n){
  x <- runif(n,min = -5,max = 5)
  y <- ifelse(x < 0,-1,1)
  return(data.frame(x,y))
}

# Objective function L_D
obj_fun <- function(X,y,alpha){
  N <- length(X) 
  inner.product <- numeric(N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    for(k in 1:N){
      inner.product[k] <- alpha[i]*alpha[k]*
        y[i]*y[k]*(t(as.numeric(X[i]))%*%as.numeric(X[k]))
    }
  }
  L_D <- sum(alpha) - 0.5*sum(inner.product)
  return(L_D)
}

# L_D works when N = 10
set.seed(4997)
options(digits = 4,scipen = -4)
N = 10
sample.data <- gen.sample(n=N)
X.data <- sample.data$x
y.vec <- sample.data$y

alpha.vector <- matrix(rep(c(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5),11*N),ncol = 11, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
for(j in 1:N){
  alpha.vector[j,2] <- rnorm(1,5,5)
}

for(i in 1:N){
  print(obj_fun(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha.vector[i,]))
}

# It produces all NA when N = 12

set.seed(4997)
options(digits = 4,scipen = -4)
N = 12
sample.data <- gen.sample(n=N)
X.data <- sample.data$x
y.vec <- sample.data$y

alpha.vector <- matrix(rep(c(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5),11*N),ncol = 11, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
for(j in 1:N){
  alpha.vector[j,2] <- rnorm(1,5,5)
}

for(i in 1:N){
  print(obj_fun(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha.vector[i,]))
}
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
```

What goes wrong? I do not see the issue.

Any help would be great!

Comment: In the tex-formatted math equation that you just added, what are the dimensions of alpha, y, and x?  Are they all length-n vectors?  Or is x an n*n matrix? Or something else?

Comment: @DanY Hello Dan, the dimension of alpha should be a vector 1 by N, y should be a vector of 1 by N, and x is the data (for this simple case), 1 by N. Later on when I get my code to work for 1D data, I will modify it more to work for 2D case. All I want to do now is to evaluate my function L_D and plot it to see if it is quadratic or not.

Comment: I just amended my answer below to include `newfun()` which I believe is a faithful implementation of the math equation you provided above.

Comment: @DanY I fixed my code above and it works. I am still working on why my plot does not look like a quadratic function. All I did was: L_D_eval <- numeric(N)
for(i in 1:N){
  L_D_eval[i] <- print(obj_fun(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha.vector[i,]))
}
plot(L_D_eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this loop in `obj_fun` and involves what you are using for `alpha` :

```
for(i in 1:N){
    for(k in 1:N){
      inner.product[k] <- alpha[i]*alpha[k]*...
    }
  }
```

Two things:

(1) you set `N=12` but you call `obj_fun(..., alpha=alpha.vector[i,])`, where `alpha.vector[i,]` is vector of length 11.  The loop I pasted above tries to access `alpha[i]` when `i=N`, which is `NA` is because there is no 12th element in `alpha`

(2) Notice what happens when you step through your double loop: when `i=1` and `k=1`, you assign a value to `inner.product[1]`. Then `i=1` and `k=2` and you assign a value to `inner.product[2]`.  This is good until `i` changes so that `i=2`. When `i=2` and `k=1`, you overwrite `inner.product[1]` by assigning a new value to it. This continues until `i=N` and `k=N`, at which time you overwrite `inner.product[k]` for all `k`, but this time with `NA` because you perform a calculation involving `alpha[i]` and `alpha[k]` which, as just explained in (1) above, are both "outside" of `alpha`. Thus all of `inner.product` is full of `NA`'s.

---

Edit:  based on the math equation that you added to your question, and your indication that `alpha`, `x`, and `y` are all length-n vectors, I believe this function will do what you want:

```
newfun <- function(x, y, alpha) {
    axy <- alpha*x*y
    sum(alpha) - 0.5*sum(outer(axy, axy, "*"))
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks a lot for your comment. It is valuable. I was thinking of a way to evaluate a double sum.

Comment: Hi Dan, so if I want to plot my function "newfun", how can I plot that by using the idea plot(L_D~alpha.vec)? I denoted L_D<-newfun(x,y,alpha.vec)

Comment: `L_D <- newfun(...); plot(x=alpha.vec, y=L_D)`

Comment: Maybe `ay <- alpha*y; sum(alpha) - 0.5*sum(outer(ay, ay, "*")*crossprod(x))`

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
set.seed(4997)
options(digits = 4,scipen = -4)
N = 12
sample.data <- gen.sample(n=N)
X.data <- sample.data$x
y.vec <- sample.data$y

    alpha.vector <- matrix(rep(c(-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6),13*N),ncol = 13, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
    for(j in 1:N){
      alpha.vector[j,2] <- rnorm(1,5,5)
    }

for(i in 1:N){
  print(obj_fun(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha.vector[i,]))
}
```

The issue is here:

```
obj_fun <- function(X,y,alpha){

  N <- length(X) 
  inner.product <- numeric(N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    for(k in 1:N){
      inner.product[k] <- alpha[i]*alpha[k]*
        y[i]*y[k]*(t(as.numeric(X[i]))%*%as.numeric(X[k]))
    }
  }
  L_D <- sum(alpha) - 0.5*sum(inner.product)
  return(L_D)
}
```

This fuction is looping from 1 to 12 but `alpha` has not element `12` or `11`!

BTW: this looping way of doing your code can be improved by using `apply` family and others changes!

Comment: Hello, I am not sure how to use "apply" here but I will give it a shot.